# Why did they use "iron ore exports" instead of "iron ore export"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[image]

I am learning English like an ESL so if I wrote this sentence above i would use iron ore export because "port Hedland" is a singular word. Why did they do it? what does it mean?

Comment: Don't let modifiers affect your judgment. The graph is clearly counting exports > 1 (the Y axis), so *exports* is correct.

Comment: *Export* is a countable noun. One consignment of iron ore that is sent abroad is a single export. Multiple consignments constitute a number of exports. The same applies to imports. Because most companies import and export numerous consignments, these are referred to in the plural.

Comment: Agreeing with @user3169 and emphasizing that it is quite infrequent to see **export** used as a singular noun.  If you are a rug craftsman in Cambodia and make one fine rug, it's delivery to the buyer in Canada would be as an **export**. If they had ordered two rugs, or a rug and a porcelain figurine, then they would deliver **exports**.

Answer (score 3):

Export has several meanings. If you were referring to the product iron ore, you would use *export* (singular, because it's one type of product). However, your graph uses this definition:

> - Sales of goods or services abroad, or **the revenue from such sales**:
>     'meat exports'
>     <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/export)</sub>

This definition requires *exports* to be plural.

---

Whether Port Hedland is singular or plural is actually irrelevant here.